# Load multi tab Excel data into SQL Server table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a requirement that I need to load an Excel file with multiple tabs into the SQL Server table.

The Excel file contains multiple tabs with each month of data in it. I should treat the current month tab like a daily month file and import the full tab each day as a truncate and reload.

Truncate and reload raw tables for current tab and last month tab.

How do we do dynamic tab variables for identifying ingestion in SSIS?

FYI.. TABS in the Excel file are named Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, July, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec.

These tabs are named at random - not in a sequence..

Can anyone please guide me?

Here is the example how tabs are arranged.

[image]

Thank You,

Swathi.

Comment: How to read data from multiple Excel worksheets with SQL Server Integration Services https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: Using excel as a data source is done all over the place.  I think you'd be able to find plenty of useful blogs on this if you would look.  Here's one to get you started:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4157/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-worksheets-with-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: It seems that @SlawomirCieslinski and I are Google capable :)

Comment: @Greenspark It's a essential life skill ;)

Comment: ThankYou @Slawomir ,Greenspark.
I  tried looking at the example and i got this error. Any thoughts on it?
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

Comment: Go into the Data Flow task and re-open the source and it should prompt you to rebuild the metadata. Click Yes.

Comment: That error could also mean that the column headers don't all match

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make some adjusts to run in looping or if the month name of Sheets does not are the same.

1. Create one package with a Script task and, one  DTS task
   [image]
2. Create DTS variables to hold month name and Sheet Name for both months do you are loading.
   [image]
3. Edit the Script task to work with to Read and Write the variables
   [image]
4. Add the script below to select the month

   public void Main()
   {
   string[] months = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
   // Get the current month e the previous, If Jan get Dec
   int Month1 = DateTime.Now.Month - 1;
   int Month2 = Month1 == 0 ? 11 : Month1 - 1;

   Dts.Variables["User::Month1Name"].Value = months[Month1];
   Dts.Variables["User::Month1Sheet"].Value = months[Month1] + "$";
   Dts.Variables["User::Month2Name"].Value = months[Month2];
   Dts.Variables["User::Month2Sheet"].Value = months[Month2] + "$";
   }
5. Draw the DTS task as it
   [image]
6. Ajuste the Source of Excel connection to match with the variables
   [image]
7. Ajuste the Derivation column to insert the name of the month (Optional) 
   [image]

Comment: Hi Neri,
If i implement the same you showed in the images it loads all the months i specify. But i wanted to load just 2 months data at the same time not all months .
For instance, This is August so , i would like to load July and August data every day. I truncate the table and reload every day..
When i am in Sep then i should load Sep and Aug data.
Thank You so much for the detail explanation.

Comment: One question, You wrote that the Sheets are not ordered. Are the month's names always Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, July, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec? Or you need to check some register to identify the month name? How do you decide how the month is the base month to load?

Comment: Yes, The month names are always Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, July, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec. They wont be in the correct order....it is the sequence of Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Aug, July,  Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec.. This is the sequence of tab. You can see exactly what i am talking in the image i attached in the post. Thank you for the response. I will try to do what explained and will let you know how it works.

Comment: It is perfect. I created a new version, this version gets the current month and compares with previous. If you need some thing more dynamic you can put this code inside a looping

Comment: HI Neri,
I am getting this error when i tried. Any thoughts?
Exeption from HRESULT: 0xc02020E8
Error at data flow ask[Excel Source[1]]:SSIS Error code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLEDB error has occurred.Error Code:0x80040E37.

Error at data flow task[Excel Source[1]]:Opening a rowset for "Jan$" failed.check that the object exists in the database.

Comment: Sorry, yesterday was a holiday here and I was out. Maybe, it is an easy thing to resolve. Please, look at the detected sheet's name on Excel Source Editor and adjust the script. Depends on Excel driver the names can be a bit different than I used.

Comment: HI Neri,Its not the way i am expecting. I am just able to load 1 month of data i mean 1 tab from the excel..My idea to do is this way but im not sure how to do.and i dont know C# to write the code for script task.
1- Create new user variables name as CurrentMonth and PreviousMonth. 
2- Use Script Task to get values for CurrentMonth and PreviousMonth using C# code. They should be Jan, Feb,.. and so on depending on current month
3-  Use Foreach Loop to read sheets in Excel file. After this step, we should check if User::Sheetname = User::CurrentMonth or User::Sheetname=User::PreviousMonth